# Replace an entry in a pandas DataFrame using a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I'd like to change the value of an entry in a Dataframe given a condition.  For instance:

```
d = pandas.read_csv('output.az.txt', names = varname)
d['uld'] = (d.trade - d.plg25)*(d.final - d.price25)

if d['uld'] > 0:
   d['uld'] = 1
else:
   d['uld'] = 0
```

I'm not understanding why the above doesn't work.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `np.where` to set your data based on a simple boolean criteria:

```
In [3]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'uld':np.random.randn(10)})
df
Out[3]:
        uld
0  0.939662
1 -0.009132
2 -0.209096
3 -0.502926
4  0.587249
5  0.375806
6 -0.140995
7  0.002854
8 -0.875326
9  0.148876
In [4]:

df['uld'] = np.where(df['uld'] > 0, 1, 0)
df
Out[4]:
   uld
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    1
8    0
9    1
```

As for why what you did failed:

```
In [7]:

if df['uld'] > 0:
   df['uld'] = 1
else:
   df['uld'] = 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ec7d7aaa1c28> in <module>()
----> 1 if df['uld'] > 0:
      2    df['uld'] = 1
      3 else:
      4    df['uld'] = 0

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    696         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    697                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 698                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    699 
    700     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So the error is that you are trying to evaluate an array with `True` or `False` which becomes ambiguous because there are multiple values to compare hence the error. In this situation you can't really use the recommended `any`, `all` etc. as you are wanting to mask your df and only set the values where the condition is met, there is an explanation on the pandas site about this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html and a related question here: [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

[`np.where`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.where.html&ei=t3v_VMakKYvtasL5gIAL&usg=AFQjCNHtNjjelUZ9lCpoUnjgI_POsrx1Ew&bvm=bv.87611401,d.d2s) takes a boolean condition as the first param, if that is true it'll return the second param, otherwise if false it returns the third param as you want.

**UPDATE**

Having looked at this again you can convert the boolean Series to an `int` by casting using `astype`:

```
In [23]:
df['uld'] = (df['uld'] > 0).astype(int)
df

Out[23]:
   uld
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    1
8    0
9    1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm really amazed I can ask a question and receive such a detailed answer just like that. What a great experience. Thanks again!